# How to configure multiple host headers for Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure

I would like to allow multiple custom defined host headers to access my Azure Blob Storage. Is there a way to do so?

(Case-1: Success, http-200 responsed)
host header (storage.mydomain.com) --> abc.blog.blob.core.windows.net (custom domain: storage.mydomain.com)

(Case-2: Failed, http-400 responsed)
host header (newstorage.mydomain.com) --> abc.blog.blob.core.windows.net (custom domain: storage.mydomain.com)

What should I do if I need to cater "Case-2"?

p.s. I found no way to add more than one custom domain to a blob storage in Azure Management Portal.

Comment: Have you tried CNAME newstorage.mydomain.com to map to storage.mydomain.com ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible.  You can only map one CNAME to your storage account and then only use HTTP.  Keep in mind that mapping a CNAME on a CNAME won't work either (i.e. foo.domain.com -> mystorage.domain.com -> mystorage.blob.core.windows.net).  If you were to do that, storage would see the first one ('foo') and would not be able to resolve which storage account was being accessed.